# cron_schedules didn't work in wordpress

Tags: php, cron, wordpress, woocommerce

I need help to run a cron_schedules, actually i develop a plugin that will import woo-commerce product's from xml url.
Please review the below code and let me know what is the problem

```
add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'woo_add_fively_cron_schedule' );

function woo_add_fively_cron_schedule( $schedules ) {

$schedules['fively'] = array(
'interval' => 300, // Once in Five minutes
'display'  => __( 'Once in Five minutes' ),
);

return $schedules;
}

// Schedule an action if it's not already scheduled
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'woo_my_cron_action' ) ) {
wp_schedule_event( time(), 'fively', 'woo_my_cron_action' );
}

// Hook into that action that'll fire weekly
add_action( 'woo_my_cron_action', 'woo_function_to_run' );
function woo_function_to_run() {
// Add some code here
$arr_feed=wp_list_table_import(); 
$no=20;
echo "aman here";
for ($i=0;$i<count($arr_feed);$i++) 
{

    $number=get_option('number_product');
    if($number)
    {
        $no=$number;
    }
  import_product($arr_feed[$i]->url,$no);  
}
}
```

Please review the code or let me know how can i trace the problem.

Comment: Could you try to add `define('ALTERNATE_WP_CRON', true);` in your wp-config and see if it helps?

Comment: Okay thanks @vard Let me check it and get back to you.